How to create Azure ML Registry using Terraform?
How do I create Azure ML registry using terraform? I see we have a way to create Azure ML workspace (azurerm_machine_learning_workspace) and ACR as well. But I don't see a way to explicitly create ML registry or am I something? Can someone help me with it please?

Please share the code you tried @KrishnanSriram

Even I didn't found any supporting document in terraform mentioning the registry. maybe we can leverage the requirement by using CLI commands using null resource refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml/registry?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ml-registry-create


Creating Azure ML Registry using Terraform

On checking with recent most doc from harshicrop  the azure machine learning registry is missing from the provider.
In order to achieve your requirement we need to use null resource where we can pass the CLI commands using terraform.
As per the MSDoc we can create the registry for ml using the commands in null resource using terraform
Configuration:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "null_resource" "create_ml_registry" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      az ml registry create --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name} --file "${path.module}/registry.yml"
    EOT
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
  }
}

Deployment:



Is there a way to create it using AzAPI as opposed to null_resource?

Added another answer with the azapi resource

Another option, using the azapi resource
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source  = "azure/azapi"
      version = "~> 2.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azapi" {
  # subscription_id = "..."
}

locals {
  location            = "East US" # Note: Update these as appropriate
  resource_group_name = "myrg"
  registry_name       = "my-registry"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "default" {
  name     = local.resource_group_name
  location = local.location
}

resource "azapi_resource" "ml_registry" {
  type      = "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/registries@2024-04-01"
  name      = local.registry_name
  location  = azurerm_resource_group.default.location
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.default.id

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  body = {
    properties = {
      regionDetails = [
        {
          location = azurerm_resource_group.default.location
          storageAccountDetails = [
            {
              systemCreatedStorageAccount = {
                storageAccountType = "Standard_LRS"
              }
            }
          ],
          acrDetails = [
            {
              systemCreatedAcrAccount = {
                acrAccountSku = "Premium"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


